# R find rows starting with a group of numeric characters

Tags: r

I'm trying to fix zip code entry errors using the first two prefixes. As a reproducible example, (hypothetically) suppose that the zip codes start with 01, 02, 03, and 04 are MA but my data contains error as the following.

```
ma_zip <- c("01", "02", "03", "04")

df <- data.frame(zip = c("01100", "02223", "04332", "03234"),
                 state = c("MA", "NJ", "NY", "NY")) %>%
  mutate(zip = as.character(zip),
         state = as.character(state))
```

I tried fixing the error in the following two ways. In the first (and brute force) approach, I fixed it one by one and get the result I want.

```
df_cleaned1 <- df %>%
  mutate(state = replace(state, startsWith(zip, "02"), "MA"),
         state = replace(state, startsWith(zip, "03"), "MA"),
         state = replace(state, startsWith(zip, "04"), "MA"))

> df_cleaned1
    zip state
1 01100    MA
2 02223    MA
3 04332    MA
4 03234    MA
```

But this is not the funniest thing to do, as I have to copy and paste repeatedly. So I tried the following instead but this doesn't seem to work (no error message is thrown either).

```
df_cleaned2 <- df %>%
  mutate(state = replace(state, startsWith(zip, paste(ma_zip, collapse="|")), "MA"))

> df_cleaned2
    zip state
1 01100    MA
2 02223    NJ
3 04332    NY
4 03234    NY
```

Is there an efficient way to produce `df_cleaned1` while avoiding the brute force approach? (Doesn't have to use startWith function)

Comment: Just a comment that [this table suggests](http://www.structnet.com/instructions/zip_min_max_by_state.html) that New Hampshire and Maine zip codes can start with "03" and "04"... if that table is accurate, and if the ranges are non-overlapping--the Virginia ranges look sloppy) it might be better (and easier) to treat the zip code as a numeric and use `cut` to bin it into the correct state.

Comment: Oh sorry for the confusion. The MA zip codes above are hypothetical. I fixed the above accordingly.

Comment: Glad to hear, just checking!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `str_sub` from `stringr` to get the first 2 characters and use that with `%in%`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
     mutate(state = replace(state, str_sub(zip, 1, 2) %in% ma_zip,
              'MA'))
```

---

Or another option is regex

```
df %>%
    mutate(state = replace(state, str_detect(zip, str_c("^(", str_c(ma_zip, collapse="|"), ")")), 'MA'))
#   zip state
#1 01100    MA
#2 02223    MA
#3 04332    MA
#4 03234    MA
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(state = replace(state, substr(zip, 1, 2) %in% ma_zip, 'MA'))
```

Output:

```
    zip state
1 01100    MA
2 02223    MA
3 04332    MA
4 03234    MA
```

Comment: Oh, this is a nice and simple get around. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here are some base R solution

```
df <- within(df, state <- replace(state,gsub("(\\w{2}).*","\\1",zip) %in% ma_zip,"MA"))
```

or

```
df <- within(df, state <- replace(state,substr(zip,1,2) %in% ma_zip,"MA"))
```

such that

```
> df
    zip state
1 01100    MA
2 02223    MA
3 04332    MA
4 03234    MA
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `grepl` instead of `startsWith`. You will need to create the following pattern `^01|^02|^03|^04`, which can be done using paste function with some modification of your approach (@qnp1521):

`df_cleaned2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(state = replace(state, grepl(paste("^",ma_zip, collapse ="|",sep=""),zip), "MA"))`

```
df_cleaned2
1 01100    MA
2 02223    MA
3 04332    MA
4 03234    MA
```